# SQL Rows to Columns Pivot?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a database that is structured as follows:

```
Time | Label | Reading | Units
13:50 | A1 | 20.45 | V
13:50 | A1 | 20.33 | W
13:50 | A2 | 8.55 | V
13:50 | A2 | 8.67 | W
```

What I am trying to do is split the Units column into a V column and a W column and group by the Label but I cannot get it to work. Do I have to use the Pivot function?

What I would like the table to look like:

```
Time | Label | V | W
13:50 | A1 |  20.45 | 20.33
13:50 | A2 | 8.55 | 8.67
```

Answer (score 1):

You want conditional aggregation :

```
select time, label,
       max(case when Units = 'V' then reading end) as V,
       max(case when Units = 'W' then reading end) as W
from table t
group by time, label;
```

Comment: Thank you! Works as expected!